# Dialog's ViewModel and View creating new objects and not deleting previous

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing MVVM C# WPF application.
I'm currently fixing memory leaks because they slow down program overtime.

I have Settings window and ViewModel attached to it. My problem is that program is creating new objects and doesn't remove and delete previous.

Picture:
[image]
As you can see +6 is new ViewModel,Views object created from first screenshot I have taken.

What I have tried:
Create instance of View and when it is null create new one and when it isn't use saved view. Didn't work, it did work on ViewModels in UserControl

```
 var dialog = new SettingsWindow();
 dialog.ShowDialog();
```

I create it in other ViewModel like this. Why object still exist even when settings window is closed?
Thank you for all answers

Comment: This behavior is to be expected. The garbage collector will free the memory eventually (if it is not referenced any more), but it will not free the memory immediately. The garbage collector will run if memory pressure increases.

Comment: I have even tried now run GC.collect() manually and it didn't help too

Comment: If you don't reference objects any more, the memory they consume will eventually(!) be freed by the GC. This doesn't mean that the memory will be freed on the first run of the GC. It may take multiple runs until memory is freed. What you need to do is: Make sure you don't reference the objects you don't need any more. With managed resources, that's all there is to it. For deeper understanding, consult the GC documentation.